# A solution for a general functional equation.

Tags: functions, soft-question

I recently found a problem that stated

Show that there does not exist a function $f(n)$ so that $f(f(n))=b+1987$.

I solved this problem, but doing so, I made this claim and I wish to see if it is true. Namely:

Claim: If a function $f(n)$ that maps $N$ to $N$, and if $f(n)=n+b$, then $b$ is even.

Proof: Assume $b$ is odd. Then we have $f(n)$ is not an integer, since $b=1(mod 2)$. //

Final: So $f(f(n))=n+b$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is even. (We are always mapping from $N$ to $N$).

Comment: Do you mean "if $f(f(n)) = n+b$ for all $n$, then $b$ is even"?  Your proof makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean. I am not the best at explaining things.